# selecting a range of columns in database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2007

how can i select a range of columns in a database(Sqlserver eg..)
i have name,id,and a dynamically created columns named after dates..

do if i query from 1-1-2011 to 16-1-2011 ..the query should return all the dates between   that range...
excluding Sundays...

i am using access db with c#

so...i try is to select the columns from start date till we reach end date..
but how can it be done..(this removes Sundays too..:) )

also cant columns be selected using a index or something...like in arrays??

eg.schema  is like this,,,,,column names are (id,name,'1-1-2011','2-1-2011','4-1-2011','6-1-2011','6-1-2011')..how do i display all rows from 2-1-2011 to 6-1-2011?

Comment: Show some code please. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("Select ID,Name ")
    DateTime begindate=DateTime.Parse("2-1-2011");
    DateTime enddate=DateTime.Parse("6-1-2011");
    DateTime tempDate = begindate;
    while(tempDate<=enddate )
    {
        if(tempDate.DayOfWeek!=DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            if (tempDate==begindate )
            {
                query.Append(",");
            }
            query.Append(","+tempDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        }
        tempDate = tempDate.AddDays(1);
    }
    query.Append(" From table Name");
```

then execute the generated select statement.

Comment: An actual answer would also limit the date range, not just eliminate the Sundays. The reason that's important is because you need the date range limitation not just for the correct answer, but in order to make the query efficient, since using a function in the WHERE clauses means indexes won't be used for that part of the comparison.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton I think that will cover your comments, Thanks

Comment: note:the column names are itself dates...so  how do i select them..get it..

Comment: eg.schema  is like this,,,,,column names are (id,name,'1-1-2011','2-1-2011','4-1-2011','6-1-2011','6-1-2011')..how do i display all rows from 2-1-2011 to 6-1-2011?

Comment: @Suraj I can not imagin why you use the date as column name, Do you mean your table has dynamic column or what? if that table created in run time so you can create the `select` query and pass it to sql server to be executed.

Comment: yes,the table columns are created dynamically...so i cant say how may columns to ask...if i try select * from table..it shows all..i require only from a specific range..:(...i was guessing if there was a way to index the columns..then i could start from that index till the end index.....??

Comment: wow.. thanks a lot microprocessor....a quick doubt...or advise for me...i have to execute 8 select queries which return single row outputs...i had to add 8 datagridviews to display each in every view..is there a better way to display 8 query outputs..note:all queries dont have same schema...

Comment: :) my nick name is **miroprocessor** not **microprocessor**.you can create any number of queries you want using the same approach the pass it to stored procedure and receive the output into one dataset that you can bind it to DataGridViews.